# How to make Opera open search results in a new tab, like Firefox?

Tags: search, opera

In Firefox you can highlight a word on a web page, right click, and google it.  The results opens in a new tab in the background.

Opera has the same thing, the only problem is that it opens the results on the web page you are currently viewing.  How can you make it open in a new tab (preferably in the background) like Firefox?

Comment: Hmmm. For me (10.51), it opens in a new tab (in foreground, though). I can't find an option to set this behavior, though.

Comment: @Gnoupi - this behavior was added to the version before 10.51. The original release of 10 was as the OP described. I would like the option to open the search results in either foreground or background. I would also like the search term to be automatically copied to the clipboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Opera version are you using? According to [this thread](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=408491), searching using the context menu **always** opens in a new tab - which is the behavior I am seeing with 10.51, regardless of whether "Reuse current tab" is checked in Preferences -> Advanced -> Tabs (although it does affect searching from the search box).

Comment: I upgraded Opera and now it works the way I want it to.

Answer (score 3):

Opera 11:
Preferences | Advanced | Tabs
Uncheck "Reuse existing"
Check "Open new tab next to active"
May be more steps than necessary, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

#### Keyboard Shortcuts

Open tab as a new tab

> Shift + Left click » Search

Open tab as a background tab

> Ctrl + Shift + Left click » Search